# Send Voip Push On development but not on production

Tags: c#, .net, apple-push-notifications, voip

i Am Using **JsSoft.Apple.Apns.Notification** . When i do sandbox= true. it works fine but when i change into **false** Notification is not received. also i No error will be arise. Please Tell Me what i missed or Doing wrong? 
Apple .p12 Certificate is Created  for Production. 
here is the Code. or (https://github.com/Redth/APNS-Sharp).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using JdSoft.Apple.Apns.Notifications;

namespace JdSoft.Apple.Apns.Test
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Variables you may need to edit:
            //---------------------------------

            //True if you are using sandbox certificate, or false if using production
            bool sandbox = false;

            //Put your device token in here
            string testDeviceToken = "7e6baf66c0a908f65e15b9575dd04c291021b7b77079624223b39cd053d38c26";

            //Put your PKCS12 .p12 or .pfx filename here.
            // Assumes it is in the same directory as your app
            string p12File = @"C:\Users\Nouman\source\repos\AsteriskComunicationApi\AsteriskComunicationApi\p12File\VOIP_iOS_New.p12";

            //This is the password that you protected your p12File 
            //  If you did not use a password, set it as null or an empty string
            string p12FilePassword = "12345678";

            //Number of notifications to send
            int count = 3;

            //Number of milliseconds to wait in between sending notifications in the loop
            // This is just to demonstrate that the APNS connection stays alive between messages
            int sleepBetweenNotifications = 3000;


            //Actual Code starts below:
            //--------------------------------

            string p12Filename = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, p12File);

            NotificationService service = new NotificationService(sandbox, p12Filename, p12FilePassword, 1);

            service.SendRetries = 5; //5 retries before generating notificationfailed event
            service.ReconnectDelay = 5000; //5 seconds

            service.Error += new NotificationService.OnError(service_Error);
            service.NotificationTooLong += new NotificationService.OnNotificationTooLong(service_NotificationTooLong);

            service.BadDeviceToken += new NotificationService.OnBadDeviceToken(service_BadDeviceToken);
            service.NotificationFailed += new NotificationService.OnNotificationFailed(service_NotificationFailed);
            service.NotificationSuccess += new NotificationService.OnNotificationSuccess(service_NotificationSuccess);
            service.Connecting += new NotificationService.OnConnecting(service_Connecting);
            service.Connected += new NotificationService.OnConnected(service_Connected);
            service.Disconnected += new NotificationService.OnDisconnected(service_Disconnected);

            //The notifications will be sent like this:
            //      Testing: 1...
            //      Testing: 2...
            //      Testing: 3...
            // etc...
            for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
            {
                //Create a new notification to send
                Notification alertNotification = new Notification(testDeviceToken);

                alertNotification.Payload.Alert.Body = string.Format("Testing {0}...", i);
                alertNotification.Payload.Sound = "default";
                alertNotification.Payload.Badge = i;

                //Queue the notification to be sent
                if (service.QueueNotification(alertNotification))
                    Console.WriteLine("Notification Queued!");
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("Notification Failed to be Queued!");

                //Sleep in between each message
                if (i < count)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Sleeping " + sleepBetweenNotifications + " milliseconds before next Notification...");
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(sleepBetweenNotifications);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Cleaning Up...");

            //First, close the service.  
            //This ensures any queued notifications get sent befor the connections are closed
            service.Close();

            //Clean up
            service.Dispose();

            Console.WriteLine("Done!");
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }           
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you use different provisions profiles when build Dev and Prod versions of your iOS app?